# higher derivatives

Tags: derivatives

*Use the product rule three times to find a formula for (fg)''' and compare the result with the expansion (a+b)<sup>3</sup>. Then try to guess a general formula for (fg)<sup>(n)</sup>.*

I don't really understand what they are asking me here and it would be really helpful if someone could explain it to me.

Comment: Have you done what the question has asked? Have you calculated the third derivative and the expansion?

Comment: The problem is that if the lecturer asks: please, differentiate twice, say, $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^2}$, it is not a problem for a student. But of one asks in general: differentiate a product $fg$ several times, it is a great problem. What have I given? This is a student's question.

Comment: Do you know the formula for $(fg)'?$

Comment: Try differentiating $fg$ once and see what you get - that is simply the product rule and has two terms. Then differentiate that a second time applying the product rule to each term. Then do the same for a third time, At each stage you will have terms you can collect together - you should get three terms for the second derivative and four for the third once you have collected similar terms together, Observe the pattern. This is one of those questions where you just have to try it and see what comes out - if I do it for you, you will learn much less than if you do it yourself.

Comment: @DanRust yes , but i don't understand the part where they ask me to find the general formula.

Comment: Do you happen to remember the binomial theorem?

Comment: @DanRust I've never used the binomial theorem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down.

> Use the product rule three times to find a formula for $(fg)''' \ldots$

This means to compute the third derivative of the function $h(x) = f(x)g(x)$. That is, find the derivative $h',$ then differentiate that again, and then differentiate the result. (Cf. second derivative.)

> ...and compare the result with the expansion $(a+b)^3.$

You can just do the ordinary FOIL technique, or, if you know the binomial theorem (which is a big plus here), use it. See what the two expansions have in common.

> Then try to guess a general formula for $(fg)^{(n)}.$

Can you find the pattern and find a formula for an $n$-th derivative of a product?

These are all the hints I'll give.

Answer (score 0):

We apply the product (and sum) rules on derivatives:
$$\matrix{(fg)'&=&f'g+fg' \\
(fg)''&=&(f'g+fg')'&=&(f'g)' +(fg')'=&\dots \\
(fg)'''&=&\dots}$$